# Bulk save to mongo db using Morphia

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I have a list of data object which has to be saved in `mongodb`.
if `datastore.save(ListofObject)` is used will it degrade the performance.`Morphia version is 1.1.0` and `java jdk 1.8`

Comment: welcome to SO! - could you be more specific/detailed?

Comment: what performance are we talking about. please be a little more specific. using morphia will almost always have a performance overhead due to obvious reasons. But if it is too much you can resort to the java driver

Comment: The time needed to save using datastore.save(ListofObject) method will be less or more compared to passing of each object inside for loop as datastore.save(Object)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Suppose if entity name is User,

```java
Query<User> query = MongoUtils.getDataStore()
  .createQuery(User.class)
  .filter("active", Boolean.TRUE)
  .filter("suspensionDate <", new Date());

UpdateOperations<User> updateOperations = MongoUtils.getDataStore()
  .createUpdateOperations(User.class)
  .set("active", false);
```

```java
UpdateResults updateResults = MongoUtils.getDataStore()
  .update(query, updateOperations, false, null);
```

In the above case the all user with flag active true and suspension date less that today will be set with flag active false.

If total records updated need to know then below lines are useful.

```java
WriteResult writeResult = updateResults.getWriteResult();
int totalRecordsUpdated = writeResult.getN();
```